# Fill NA Values in pandas Series with a stop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm analyzing a time series, and based on certain criteria, I can pick out rows that are either the **start** or the **end** of the events. At this point, my series looks something like this (I've left out some repetitive values for brevity):

#### The Setup

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
from pandas import Timestamp

datadict = {'event': {
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:20:00', tz=None): 'event start',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:30:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:40:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 00:50:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 01:00:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 01:10:00', tz=None): 'event end',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 01:20:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 02:20:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 02:30:00', tz=None): 'event start',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 02:40:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 02:50:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 03:00:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 03:10:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 03:20:00', tz=None): '--',
  Timestamp('2010-01-01 03:30:00', tz=None): 'event end',
}}
data = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(datadict)

                           event
2010-01-01 00:20:00  event start
2010-01-01 00:30:00           --
2010-01-01 00:40:00           --
2010-01-01 00:50:00           --
2010-01-01 01:00:00           --
2010-01-01 01:10:00    event end
2010-01-01 01:20:00           --
2010-01-01 02:20:00           --
2010-01-01 02:30:00  event start
2010-01-01 02:40:00           --
2010-01-01 02:50:00           --
2010-01-01 03:00:00           --
2010-01-01 03:10:00           --
2010-01-01 03:20:00           --
2010-01-01 03:30:00    event end
```

#### Here's what I would like to achieve (*ideally without `for` loops*)

```
                           event  event number
2010-01-01 00:20:00  event start  1
2010-01-01 00:30:00           --  1
2010-01-01 00:40:00           --  1
2010-01-01 00:50:00           --  1
2010-01-01 01:00:00           --  1
2010-01-01 01:10:00    event end  1
2010-01-01 01:20:00           --  NA
2010-01-01 02:20:00           --  NA
2010-01-01 02:30:00  event start  2
2010-01-01 02:40:00           --  2
2010-01-01 02:50:00           --  2
2010-01-01 03:00:00           --  2
2010-01-01 03:10:00           --  2
2010-01-01 03:20:00           --  2
2010-01-01 03:30:00    event end  2
2010-01-01 03:40:00           --  NA
2010-01-01 03:50:00           --  NA
```

#### Here's what I've tried

With some optimistic assumptions about the quality of my data, I can get **Event Numbers** like this:

```
table = data[data.event != '--'].reset_index()
table['event number'] = 1 + np.floor(table.index / 2)
table = table.set_index('index')

                           event  event number
index                                         
2010-01-01 00:20:00  event start             1
2010-01-01 01:10:00    event end             1
2010-01-01 02:30:00  event start             2
2010-01-01 03:30:00    event end             2
```

I can then `join` that to my original dataframe, and `fillna` with the `method='ffill'`

```
data2 = data.join(table[['event number']])
data2['filled'] = data2['event number'].fillna(method='ffill')

                           event  event number  filled
2010-01-01 00:20:00  event start             1       1
2010-01-01 00:30:00           --           NaN       1
2010-01-01 00:40:00           --           NaN       1
2010-01-01 00:50:00           --           NaN       1
2010-01-01 01:00:00           --           NaN       1
2010-01-01 01:10:00    event end             1       1
2010-01-01 01:20:00           --           NaN       1 # <- d'oh
2010-01-01 02:20:00           --           NaN       1 # <- d'oh 
2010-01-01 02:30:00  event start             2       2
2010-01-01 02:40:00           --           NaN       2
2010-01-01 02:50:00           --           NaN       2
2010-01-01 03:00:00           --           NaN       2
2010-01-01 03:10:00           --           NaN       2
2010-01-01 03:20:00           --           NaN       2
2010-01-01 03:30:00    event end             2       2
```

#### The Problem

As you can see, the time between events (01:20 through 02:20) is being associated with event #1.

#### The Question

Is there anyway to skip over these sections without looping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve this by just looking at cumulative summation of number of `event start` and number of `event end`:

```
>>> data['event number'] = (data.event == 'event start').cumsum()
>>> data
                           event  event number
2010-01-01 00:20:00  event start             1
2010-01-01 00:30:00           --             1
2010-01-01 00:40:00           --             1
2010-01-01 00:50:00           --             1
2010-01-01 01:00:00           --             1
2010-01-01 01:10:00    event end             1
2010-01-01 01:20:00           --             1
2010-01-01 02:20:00           --             1
2010-01-01 02:30:00  event start             2
2010-01-01 02:40:00           --             2
2010-01-01 02:50:00           --             2
2010-01-01 03:00:00           --             2
2010-01-01 03:10:00           --             2
2010-01-01 03:20:00           --             2
2010-01-01 03:30:00    event end             2
```

now you just need to set to `nan` when there is no event; but those places corresponds to rows where cumulative summation of `event start` is equal to cumulative summation of `event end` (with shifting 1 row)

```
>>> idx = data['event number'] == (data.event.shift(1) == 'event end').cumsum()
>>> data.loc[idx, 'event number'] = np.nan
>>> data
                           event  event number
2010-01-01 00:20:00  event start             1
2010-01-01 00:30:00           --             1
2010-01-01 00:40:00           --             1
2010-01-01 00:50:00           --             1
2010-01-01 01:00:00           --             1
2010-01-01 01:10:00    event end             1
2010-01-01 01:20:00           --           NaN
2010-01-01 02:20:00           --           NaN
2010-01-01 02:30:00  event start             2
2010-01-01 02:40:00           --             2
2010-01-01 02:50:00           --             2
2010-01-01 03:00:00           --             2
2010-01-01 03:10:00           --             2
2010-01-01 03:20:00           --             2
2010-01-01 03:30:00    event end             2

[15 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Awesome! You hit that nail right on the head. Thanks!