# Replace values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large DataFrame object where missing values are pre-coded as 0.001. These missing values only occur at the beginning of the DataFrame. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.50, 0.10, 0.001, 0.75]})
```

The problem is.... sometimes there are actual 0.001 values not at the beginning of the DataFrame that I dont want to drop (like in the example above).

What I want is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a' :[NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.50, 0.10, 0.001, 0.75]})
```

Put I can't figure out a simple way to only drop the 0.001 values at the beginning of the DataFrame, and ignore the others that occur later on.

The dataset I'm working with is massive, so I was hoping to avoide looping through each variable and each index (which is what I'm currently doing but takes a bit too long).

Any ideas?

Comment: The solution to this question that I asked might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290793/fill-na-values-in-pandas-series-with-a-stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach:

```
df.mask(df[df!=0.001].ffill().isnull(), np.nan)
Out: 
       a
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3  0.500
4  0.100
5  0.001
6  0.750
```

This first creates a boolean mask where the df does not equal `0.001`. The cells that have `0.001` will be `NaN` in this selection. If you forward fill this Series/DataFrame, the first elements will not be filled. Then you can use this as a mask to the original DataFrame.