# pandas: evaluate if condition is met for consecutive data points in a given timeframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to evaluate if a given condition (e.g. treshold) is met for a certain duration in pandas dataframe and set an output value accordingly.
E.g. set `output` to `1` if `data > treshold` for at least the next 45 min and back to `0` if `data < treshold`

What works so far (for `treshold = 3` for a minimum duration of `45 min`):

```
import pandas as pd
import random, math

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:00:00','2020-01-01 06:00:00',freq='15T')})
treshold = 3

data = []
for i in range(0,df.size):
    n = random.randint(0, 10)
    data.append(n)

df['data'] = data
df = df.set_index('dt')

timestep = df.index.to_series().diff().dt.seconds.div(3600,fill_value=None)[1]
min_duration_hours = 0.75

cell_range = math.ceil(min_duration_hours / timestep)
output = []

for i,e in enumerate(data):
    if i > (len(data) - cell_range):
        futures = data[i:len(data)]
    else:
        futures = data[i:i + cell_range]

    if i == 0:
        last = 0
    else:
        last = output[i-1]
    
    current = data[i]

    if (min(futures) > treshold or (last > 0 and current > treshold)):
        output.append(1)
    else:
        output.append(0)
    
df['output'] = output
```

result:

```
                     data  output
dt                               
2020-01-01 00:00:00     1       0
2020-01-01 00:15:00     1       0
2020-01-01 00:30:00     5       1
2020-01-01 00:45:00     6       1
2020-01-01 01:00:00     7       1
2020-01-01 01:15:00     0       0
2020-01-01 01:30:00     4       0
2020-01-01 01:45:00     5       0
2020-01-01 02:00:00     0       0
2020-01-01 02:15:00    10       1
2020-01-01 02:30:00     5       1
2020-01-01 02:45:00     9       1
2020-01-01 03:00:00     6       1
2020-01-01 03:15:00     6       1
2020-01-01 03:30:00     4       1
2020-01-01 03:45:00    10       1
2020-01-01 04:00:00     6       1
2020-01-01 04:15:00     5       1
2020-01-01 04:30:00     0       0
2020-01-01 04:45:00     8       1
2020-01-01 05:00:00     9       1
2020-01-01 05:15:00     5       1
2020-01-01 05:30:00     9       1
2020-01-01 05:45:00     6       1
2020-01-01 06:00:00     3       0
```

However, I'm wondering if there is an easier (and more efficient) way to do this with python/pandas?

Comment: what data does your variable `futures` holds ?

Comment: @k33da_the_bug the data values for the following `min_duration_hours`

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290793/fill-na-values-in-pandas-series-with-a-stop

Comment: @PaulH thanks, but this doesn't really solve the main issue of determining if the condition is met for a certain duration (or number of consecutive data points)

Comment: yeah -- it's just a launching off point. something with that and `.rolling` will get you there

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which seems to work, using `.rolling` and `.shift`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random, math

df = pd.DataFrame({'dt': pd.date_range('2020-01-01 00:00:00','2020-01-01 06:00:00',freq='15T')})
treshold = 3

data = []
for i in range(0,df.size):
    n = random.randint(0, 10)
    data.append(n)

df['data'] = data
df = df.set_index('dt')

timestep = df.index.to_series().diff().dt.seconds.div(3600,fill_value=None)[1]
min_duration_hours = 0.75

cell_range = math.ceil(min_duration_hours / timestep)

df['above_treshold'] = np.where(df['data'] > treshold, df['data'], 0)

indexer = pd.api.indexers.FixedForwardWindowIndexer(window_size=cell_range)
rolling_min_fwd = df['above_treshold'].rolling(window=indexer).min()
rolling_min_bwd = df['above_treshold'].rolling(window=cell_range).min()

shifted_fwd = df['above_treshold'].shift(1)
shifted_bwd = df['above_treshold'].shift(-1)
start_condition = ((rolling_min_fwd > 0) & ((df['above_treshold'] - shifted_fwd) == df['above_treshold']))
stop_condition = ((rolling_min_bwd > 0) & ((df['above_treshold'] - shifted_bwd) == df['above_treshold']))

cycles = start_condition.cumsum()
idx = cycles == stop_condition.shift(1).cumsum()
cycles.loc[idx] = 0
    
df['output'] = np.where(cycles > 0, 1, 0)
```

resulting in:

```
                     data  above_treshold  output
dt                                               
2020-01-01 00:00:00     8               8       0
2020-01-01 00:15:00     3               0       0
2020-01-01 00:30:00     3               0       0
2020-01-01 00:45:00     1               0       0
2020-01-01 01:00:00     3               0       0
2020-01-01 01:15:00     9               9       1
2020-01-01 01:30:00     4               4       1
2020-01-01 01:45:00     8               8       1
2020-01-01 02:00:00     6               6       1
2020-01-01 02:15:00     4               4       1
2020-01-01 02:30:00     6               6       1
2020-01-01 02:45:00     6               6       1
2020-01-01 03:00:00     1               0       0
2020-01-01 03:15:00     6               6       0
2020-01-01 03:30:00     7               7       0
2020-01-01 03:45:00     0               0       0
2020-01-01 04:00:00     2               0       0
2020-01-01 04:15:00     8               8       1
2020-01-01 04:30:00     8               8       1
2020-01-01 04:45:00     9               9       1
2020-01-01 05:00:00     1               0       0
2020-01-01 05:15:00     9               9       1
2020-01-01 05:30:00    10              10       1
2020-01-01 05:45:00     5               5       1
2020-01-01 06:00:00     8               8       1
```

Couldn't measure a significant impact on performance (working on DataFrames with > 35k data points), but still better than iterating over each datapoint (though less intuitive).